# Does Captain America have an heroic adjective like so many other Marvel characters?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

You all know the heroic adjectives of Marvel. The *Incredible* Hulk. The *Invincible* Iron Man. The *Mighty* Thor. The *Spectacular* Spider-Man. The *Uncanny* X-Men. But from what I can tell, the big-name Captain America doesn't get one of those. It could be that the rank of Captain counts to this purpose, but most of the others have names that work perfectly fine without them (though the Fantastic Four might run into a snatch with this). And the last time I checked, America isn't an adjective.

So does Captain America have one of these heroic adjectives, either in the title of his books or used for him in said books? Or have the writers neven given him one, possibly because he predates the others?

Comment: I first read this question 20 minutes ago, and I've had "The Star-Spangled Man With A Plan" playing in my head ever since.

Comment: I believe Spider-Man is actually "Amazing".  He wasn't "Spectacular" until the sales warranted a second series.

Comment: I just watched *The Iceman*. I think we can call Capt. America Capt *Mr Freezy* America.

Comment: What, like "The Captainest Captain America"?

Comment: Jokes aside; Captain in this case could be an adjective, he's as Captainy as it gets. It's *what* he is and not just *who* he is.

Comment: His name is "America".. The prefix is *Captain*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Captain America was often referred to during the seventies and eighties as "The Star-Spangled Avenger." When addressed informally by his friends or long-term acquaintances who might not know he was Steve Rogers, he was called "Cap."

- Strangely enough, looking back over the years, Captain America's cover did NOT boast a particular tagline until recently when he became "The First Avenger." The stylized red, white and blue, "Captain America" was all Cap needed for a decade or more. Later when he and Falcon teamed up, the logo became "Captain America and the Falcon".

[image]

[image]

- Depending on who you were asking, he might also get the name: "Wing-head" for the wings which were on his costume during certain periods.

[image]

- Hawkeye was known for his complete disrespect of Captain America in Hawkeye's early days of avenging. He was known to call Captain America such colorful names as "Glamour Pants, Curly, and Methuselah."

[image]

Comment: Curious: was "The Star-Spangled Avenger" ever the title of a series, the way the ones quoted in the question were?

Comment: No. Captain America, Captain America and the Falcon and Captain America, the First Avenger are the major titles Captain America starred in.

Comment: At the time that Hawkeye called him that was Captain America actually the oldest member of the Avengers? Or where there other members of the Avengers at that point that were older than him?

Comment: +1. I am almost always stunned by the amount of information the people in SciFi could deliver.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs I don't know if Thor was an active member of the Avengers at the time of that comic, but he was one of the original members, and he's obviously older than Cap.

Answer (score -2):

What about "The original Avenger" ? That title has been used in the past. Not short like some of the other titles though.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, "The original Avenger" was only used as a [the subtitle](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Captain-America-The-Original-Avenger-DVD-/161433878005) of the [1990 film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cs8rFsmhNTc), not in any of the comics.

Comment: In the animated series Avengers - Earth's mightiest heroes he was "The First Avenger" during the intro.

Answer (score -3):

*Captain*.

Comment: The Captain Captain? No.

Comment: @Richard: :whoosh: